# JSON in API call is not decoding correctly, I am getting a blank struct

Tags: json, go

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "website": {
    "id": 8,
    "account_id": 9,
    "name": "max",
    "website_url": "",
    "subscription_status": "trial",
    "created_at": "2016-01-24T01:43:41.693Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-02-21T01:17:53.129Z",
  }
}
```

My Website struct looks like this:

```
type Website struct {
    Id                    int64     `json:"id"`
    AccountId             int64     `json:"account_id"`
    Name                  string    `json:"name"`
    WebsiteUrl            string    `json:"website_url"`
    SubscriptionStatus    string     `json:"subscription_status"`
    CreatedAt             time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt             time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
}
```

I then have a Company struct like:

```
type Company struct {
  Website Website
  api *API
}
```

So in my API client code I have this:

```
res, status, err := api.request(endpoint, "GET", nil, nil)

if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
if status != 200 {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Status returned: %d", status)
}

r := map[string]Company{}
err = json.NewDecoder(res).Decode(&r)

fmt.Printf("things are: %v\n\n", r)
```

The output I am getting is this:

```
things are: map[website:{{0 0          0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC} <nil>}]
```

How can I debug this, I am not sure why it is not setting the Website struct with correct values.

**Update**

I added this, I don't see any output:

```
if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error is not nillllllll!!!:")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return nil, err
    }
```

Comment: check the error from `Decode`.

Comment: @hobbs I updated my question with the error code, I don't see any output.

Answer (score 2):

Its because you have too many levels of nesting with the `map` > `Company` > `Website`. The `map` effectively builds another layer on top of it so its expecting three levels of JavaScript objects nested. In actuality, the JSON you provided only has two with `Company` > `Website`.

So there are a couple of ways to get it to work; choose the one that works best for you.

You can do:

```
r := map[string]Website{}
json.NewDecoder(res).Decode(&r)
```

Or you can do:

```
r := Company{}
json.NewDecoder(res).Decode(&r)
```

Comment: thanks!  btw, any links to a production example of a API client that I should look at?

Comment: No problem! I tend to just use the `http.Client` and add another layer of abstraction if I need something more domain specific. Not sure if that helps.